# Mongoid find_by fails with Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound: if have another validation line

Tags: mongoid

As seen below, I have a very simple class that has two validation lines, the second of which needs to be commented-out in order for find_by to work.  It does not seem to make a difference what the nature of the second line is.  Appears to be a bug.  (Note that I wanted post this issue on the Mongoid mailing-list, but was informed that it was not accepting new members.)

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem "mongoid", "~> 3.0.0" 


uhoh.rb
============================================================
class Uhoh < Object
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :f1, type: String
  field :f2, type: String
  validates :f1, presence: true
  validates :f2, presence: false  ##### Get error below if this line NOT commented out
end


uhoh_test.rb
============================================================
require 'test_helper'
class TestUhoh < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_1
    Mongoid.purge!
    Uhoh.create(f1: 'a')
    self.assert_nothing_raised(Exception){Uhoh.find_by(f1: 'a')}
  end
end


Test result, with line NOT commented out
============================================================
C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e
$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) -Itest
C:/Users/PJD/RubymineProjects/Metronome/test/unit/uhoh_test.rb
Testing started at 7:25 PM ...
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Run options: 

# Running tests:

E

Finished tests in 0.045003s, 22.2207 tests/s, 22.2207 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
test_1(TestUhoh):
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound: 
Problem:
  Document not found for class Uhoh with attributes {:f1=>"a"}.
Summary:
  When calling Uhoh.find_by with a hash of attributes, all attributes
  provided must match a document in the database or this error will be
  raised.
Resolution:
  Search for attributes that are in the database or set the
  Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which
  will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error.
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.21/lib/mongoid/finders.rb:96:in `find_by'
    C:/Users/PJD/RubymineProjects/Metronome/test/unit/uhoh_test.rb:6:in `block in test_1'

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

Process finished with exit code 1


Test result, with line YES commented out
============================================================
C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e
$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) -Itest
C:/Users/PJD/RubymineProjects/Metronome/test/unit/uhoh_test.rb
Testing started at 7:26 PM ...
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Run options: 

# Running tests:

.

Finished tests in 0.039003s, 25.6391 tests/s, 25.6391 assertions/s.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this code example works when run in `mongoid 4.0.0.alpha1`  I'd guess somebody squashed the bug.

Answer (score 4):

you can set your mongoid yml to avoid not found error.

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: db_development      
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```